# Creating a CRUD model in Sencha Architect 2 using restproxy?

Tags: extjs, sencha-touch-2, crud, sencha-architect

I have been working on a CRUD model on Sencha Architect 2 for almost 3 days now but I am getting stuck somewhere or the other. If someone out there has worked on a similar project or if someone could give me some advice on how to go about it, it would be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: what do you mean by "stuck somewhere or the other"?

Comment: I have made a form in architect and I want the data to be stored here-  http://svc2-staging.mypsn.com/v1/cams/resources
I am making changes in the form and they are working fine on the client side but the changes are not being reflected in the url.